# Not able to understand iOS System UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, uipasteboard

i am working on custom emoji keyboard it is an keyboard extension and problem is that on clicking button i need to copy image in pasteboard and paste it into another app . i have used these code but not able to copy image into pasteboard

-code in .h file

```
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard_img;
```

-code in viewDidLoad()

```
    pasteboard_img = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
```

-code in method which is call when button is pressed on keyboard

```
    [pasteboard_img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[array_image objectAtIndex:sender.tag]]];
```

~ where array_image is array with image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pasteboard_img.persistent=YES;
```

Use this.

Comment: How does this add to the already given answer? It contributes nothing extra